# Laravel where and fallback to orWhere not working as expected in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working in a Laravel 8 project. I have a query that queries my `Brand` model. A `Brand` can have many `Affiliate` models, and there can only ever be one `is_default` affiliate.

I need to return a single affiliate by the request's affiliate query option, or, if this can't be found, fallback to searching for the `is_default`, if neither is found, return null.

This is my query so far:

```php
$brand = Brand::where('slug', $request->input('slug'))
                ->where('uuid', $request->input('uuid'))
                ->with([
                'latest_affiliate' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->where('affiliate', $request->input('affiliate', null))
                            ->orWhere('is_default', true);
                }
                ])
                ->first();
```

I thought this would work since my `latest_affiliate` relationship only returns one entry. But when I make my query, and purposly send a request where there is no affiliate but is a default affiliate, the returned response is null for affiliate. What am I missing?

```php
/**
 * Get the affiliates for the brand.
 */
public function affiliates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Affiliate::class);
}

/**
 * Get the latest affiliate of many
 */
public function latest_affiliate()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Affiliate::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```